# Why should we avoid to use "hi" and "thank you" but "haha", "lol" and "lmao"?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I know that in many questions/answers, the words "*Hi everyone!*" or "*Thank you!*" will be removed automatically.

But why in many questions/answers, I saw that there were many people still using the words "*lol*", "*lmao*" or "*:-)*" to show their feeling (instead of using emoji icon), maybe there was no one who wanted to edit the question/answer just to remove that words?

I'm a businessman. So, there is no "*lol*" and *"lmao"* in my emails but they start with *"Dear"* and end with a signature.

Comment: "lol", "lmao", etc are noise just like "hi". And should also be edited out.

Comment: Since you are new in meta: please do not worry about downvotes to the question here. They do not affect your account or reputation in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are context-specifically the same. In a question, for instance: 
*(examples are freely invented)*

> so i tried to write this program to calculate the primes between two
>   input numbers but every time I run it my pc dies lol :( anyway here's
>   the code:

You'd edit the unnecessary clutter out of it, into something like this:

> I made a program to calculate all primes between to input numbers. However, when I try to run the program, my PC crashes with a bluescreen. Here's the code for the program:

This is a different kind of clutter (overly colloquial language / slang) then thank you and salutations are, but it's still just clutter, so edit it out just the same. Hardly anyone will decline edit suggestions making the tone and demeanor of questions and answers more professional.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the information. It's helpful!